# What is the convention to handle secondary action of UIButton in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, conventions, ibaction

I have a `UIButton` which is used to do something when user touch the button. I did it in `Touch Up Inside`. I have to implement another function which is treated as like a secondary action for that `UIButton`.

What is the **convention** in iOS to handle more than one action for same `UIButton`? Should I use

> double-tap action

or

> long press gesture

or anything else?

Comment: Is there a third action?

Comment: No, only two action from same UIButton

Comment: So you can use selected state of button, when user first click on button - set it selected, then when again click on button check if button is selected - if yes -it's second action else it's first one.

Comment: It is a switch, so On/Off is used there. I need to implement channel assign there.

Comment: In my opening its better to implement long press with action information to user.

Answer (score 0):

For maintaining the App I would not advise implementing 2 IBactions on a button. 
I would suggest creating an IBAction routine which initiates both actions.

Answer (score -1):

Set tag of the button inside method, set default tag is 0,

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
    UIButton *mybtn = (UIButton*)sender;
    if (mybtn.tag == 0) {
        //perform fist action
        //set btn tag to 1
        mybtn.tag = 1;
    }
    else if (mybtn.tag == 1)
    {
        //perform second action
        //set btn tag to 0
        mybtn.tag = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

As Imad suggested, use a bool called isClickedOnce (default is false), when user click first time then set value to true.

```
var isClickedOnce = false

func switchAction(){
    if isClickedOnce{
      print("Second")
    }else{
      isClickedOnce = true
      print("First")
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to assign channel. The question was handle secondary action! not how to do different task from same action.

Comment: Did you mean 2 tap on single session consecutively?

Comment: I have a UIButton which is a swich, so ON/Off is implemented. I need to implement assign channel on same UIButton so that user can select the channel to control. I did it in long press gesture. Is it the convention? My English is poor! Can you please suggest any edit on the question?

Comment: What do you mean by assign channel on same button?